# Language selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been researching around for code that will let me click an `<a>` tag to convert the page's language to a different language using a key value pair, but the countless ones that I've found online lurking around seems to be tailored for its own personal needs or incomplete.

So my question is, how would I go about changing every element with a certain class to the language from the `<a>` tag I clicked, while using the dictionary keypair?

Here's my current JQuery/JS code:

```js
var langcodes = [{
  code: "en",
  name: "English",
}, {
  code: "zh-Hant",
  name: "Traditional",
}, {
  code: "zh-Hans",
  name: "Simplified",
}, {
  code: "vi",
  name: "Vietnamese",
}];

var dictionary = [{
    //Word one
    English: "Abby",
    Traditional: "AbbyT",
    Simplified: "AbbyS",
    Vietnamese: "AbbyV",
  }, {
    //Word two
    English: "Babby",
    Traditional: "BabbyT",
    Simplified: "BabbyS",
    Vietnamese: "BabbyV",
  },
  //and so on and so forth
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".langtype").click(function() { //click an element(language) w/ class langtype
    $(".trans").each(function(key, item) {
      //for each element with the trans class, change its text to be fitting of .langtype's language
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="navitem languagediv">
  <a>LANGUAGE&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a class="dropitem langtype">ENGLISH</a>
    <a class="dropitem langtype" href="#">繁体中文</a>
    <a class="dropitem langtype" href="#">简体中文</a>
    <a class="dropitem langtype" href="#">Tiếng Việt</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I appreciate all the help or code templates I can get. Thanks!

Comment: There's no question here, just a statement and some code. What problem are you having?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm just looking for some guidance on how to proceed with the comments I've put in the js code!

Comment: There are plenty of libraries and frameworks for translation. There's also Google Translate.

Comment: google is not always the most accurate. that's why i would like to use a keypair instead to manually add translations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to give each word or phrase in the dictionary a key and then put that key on each div that you want translated. Also put an attribute on your language selectors indicating the language that's being selected. In your `each` loop, read the `$(this).attr('key')` (if you used 'key' to set the key) and then look up the new word in the dictionary. This is a basic working example: https://jsfiddle.net/nghjucLs/

I wouldn't try to translate word by word (by scanning each `.trans` element for the word and then searching for it in the dictionary); that could get very slow with a larger dictionary and more text on the page to translate.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used this library:
http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/
to complete a similar task where I turned certain chunks of website to another language based on user feedback.

Give this a try. They give examples of use with jQuery as well.